# Add a task for a module

Tags: module, joomla-3.4, task

Is it possible to add a task to module like how you add a task (other than display()) to a component's controller?

Comment: You need component to handle task, so if you want you can link it to your component's task through href.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. You need a component to handle tasks in Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you mean a task.

You can override the files located in the tmpl folder in your template.

Check this out:

https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides